# Dropdowns for menu & search autocomplete not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have just put up a new website at [www.hcmc.com](http://www.hcmc.com).

It works great in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, but not so great in IE (surprise!).

The problems I am looking to solve are:

1. The dropdown for the top navigation menu doesn't work in IE 7 & 8
2. The autocomplete dropdown for the search box doesn't work in IE 7, 8 & 9 (try typing "pizza")

I have tried playing around with z-index, but just don't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi just a thought from my side. just try for search box, display:block; Zoom:1; *display:inline; This Hack for IE.

Comment: I saw in ur code ur using Float:left; just try with- display:inline-block; And you try with remove height and width; just try this all.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is not actual solution for your problem but i just explore my side. The browser compatability problem is solved using HTML5 BOILERPLATE. You can Combaine Twitter Bootstrap + html5 boilerplate.

1) http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
2) http://html5boilerplate.com. 
You can combine both using    http://www.initializr.com/

And for search box 
.searchbox { 
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 0 none; 
    color: #000000; 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    font: 13px/22px arial,calibri,sans-serif; 
    Zoom:1; 
   *display:inline; 
}

Try this.